# Signature interpretable in a category K

Tags: logic, category-theory, first-order-logic, exceptional-isomorphisms

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2528.pdf) on the page 10,
there is a notion of a finitary relation symbol interpretable in a category $\cal K$ with $U:{\cal K}\to \mathbb {Set}$ whose morphisms are monomorphisms preserved by $U$.

Directed colimits preserving subfunctor of $U^n$ is called relation symbol
interpretable in $\cal K$.

I do not understand how the canonical functor $G:\cal K\to \mathbb {Str(\Sigma_{\cal K})}$ works.

I also do not follow why $f:GA\to GB$ is **iso** given $f:UA\to UB$ is iso,
and given that $R(f)$ is iso for each subfunctor $R$ of $U^n$. For that $f$ being an iso means that it **both** reflects and preserves $R$. I do follow why it
preserves function symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your question. On maths.SE, it is considered good form to make questions as self-contained as possible. Could you, in light of this, edit your question to include the relevant definitions so that we may help you as good as possible?

Comment: There are a number of nontrivial and lengthy definitions involved there. I gave a reference in the OQ. If you could specify what definitions you lack, I'll add it to my OQ.

Comment: I'm afraid that upon reading more closely the linked PDF, I have to join you in not understanding what is being said there :/. Hence it is also tough to specify exactly which information is missing.